# MS Access Combobox displaying random values

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox

I have a form with a combobox and a text box.

The combobox contains data from a query.

When selecting data in the combo box, the details will be displayed in the text box.

For example the data in the combobox are [A, B, C, D .......] and i selected the letter A and it was displayed in the text box.

When selecting random options in the combobox, the details was displayed in the textbox however, the value displayed in the combo box is not the option that i have selected.

I choose C and it was displayed in the text box but in the combo box the letter displayed is random letter not C.

How to fix this?? Thanks

*Heres the code when combo box was clicked.

```
Private Sub cbocombo_Click()

    Me.txtbox1.Value = Me.cboSIDNum.Column(0)
    Me.txtbox2.Value = Me.cboSIDNum.Column(1)
    Me.txtbox3.Value = Me.cboSIDNum.Column(4)
    Me.txtbox4.Value = Me.cboSIDNum.Column(9)
    Me.txtbox5.Value = Me.cboSIDNum.Column(6)
    Me.txtbox6.Value = Me.cboSIDNum.Column(5)

End Sub
```

Comment: How are you extracting said selection?  Need to see the code before anyone can comment

Comment: i have updated the post with some codes

Comment: Look at the `.listindex` and `.list` properties of the combo box object

Comment: Are these textboxes bound to fields? If they are BOUND then you are duplicating data. There is no need to save these related data. Put expressions in UNBOUND textbox ControlSource to display related columns: `=cboSIDNum.Column(1)`. Combobox should be bound to field and saving Column(0) value to field. However, this does not explain why combobox does not display selected item - this really makes no sense and I have never seen a combobox not display selected item.

Comment: The combobox and textboxes are all unbound. Yes, the values displayed in the combobox is not consistent. Sometimes it displays the selected values sometimes a random value from the list. I also run the code line by line and once it passess the 'End Sub' of Onlick event, the displayed value in the combobox changes/resfreshes to another value.